# ERB isn't interpreting variables correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

What I'm trying to do here is to create a markdown template that allows erb too. I came with this solution:

```
class MarkdownTemplateHandler
  def call(template, source)
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

    compiled_source = erb.call(template, source)

    markdown.render(compiled_source).inspect.html_safe
  end

  private

  def erb
    @erb ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:md, MarkdownTemplateHandler.new)
```

The problem: if the `source` include something like `<%= "Hello" %>`, the result in `compiled_source` is `'.freeze; "hello" @outputbuffer.safeappend='` instead of a simple `Hello`.
Am I missing something?

PS: This example was created using rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install coderay gem to understand the source is some code, here is [the link for coderay gem](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay),

to install you can type

```
gem install coderay
```

and here is sample code to use it combined with Redcarpet Gem, you can put these code below in application_helper.rb

```
class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, language)
    CodeRay.scan(code, language).div
  end
end

def markdown(text)
  coderayified = CodeRayify.new(filter_html: true,
                                hard_wrap: true)
  options = {
    fenced_code_blocks: true,
    no_intra_emphasis: true,
    autolink: true,
    lax_html_blocks: true,
  }
  markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified, options)
  markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
end
```

and then you can call it

```
<%= markdown(your_markdown_text_variable_here) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that could make use of this:

I couldn't solve the problem originally stated in my question, but solved the problem using a different approach with [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt):

```
class MarkdownTemplateHandler
  def call(template, source)
    compiled_source = Tilt['erb'].new { source }
    compiled_source = Tilt['md'].new { compiled_source.render }

    compiled_source.render.inspect.html_safe
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:md, MarkdownTemplateHandler.new)
```